# Deserializing doctrine references with JMSSerializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle

I'm not sure how to write the title properly since I'm not sure what I'm looking for, but basically what I'm wondering if there's a way to deserialize the following json:

```
{ "title": "hello world", "user": 1 }
```

But since ***user*** is a ORM mapping, attempt to find the entity from it's repository instead of trying to parse it directly.

I can easily do this for a specific field by using a Handler for that case, pass along the EM and look the entity up, but I was hoping to come up with a more general solution where any relationship can be specified either by it's serialized fields (in order to create a new entity) or by it's id in order to lookup an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

JMSSerializer bundle requires to add an extra annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Test", mappedBy="myentity", fetch="LAZY", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateTo" = "DESC"})
 * @Expose
 * @Type("ArrayCollection<Acme\Bundle\Entity\Test>")
 */
```

Comment: I'm failing to understand what this has to do with fetching the object by id from JMSSerializer ?

Comment: `@Expose` - is the information to JMSSerializer to keep this field
`@Type` - informs to what class deserialize it

Comment: ArrayCollection makes no sense in this case, since the user is not an array